# Unit Testing implementations or wrappers of machine learning algorithms

Tags: unit-testing, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

Let's say, I have an implementation of logistic regression. Are there canned examples (say test and training sets and expected error) that I can leverage to assess that performance of my implementation is as expected?

Would be great to know how the community thinks about unit testing machine learning in general - regression, classification, unsupervised methods..

Answer (score 1):

We have generated random samples (with some structure predetermined in them) and verified our implementations by comparing them to R and/or SAS. Once the results (say the beta coefficients in logistic) were (manually) vetted to be close enough to R/SAS they were hard-coded into unit tests for the regression regression testing (pun intended) with very small tolerances. In cases there were no reference implementations, we just approved the results based on whether the learning method was able to reveal the structure and the parameters that have been put into the random sample during its generation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @jacool. We've decided to take a similar route. Things are harder when the data you deal with has a lot of features - which is how real datasets usually are. But you want to test with simplistic training sets. People however generally don't want to hand-construct training data. So basically, it would be nice to a standardized training data for testing in literature. Would be great to formalize this. Write a blog! :)